# Linq where clause invalid

Tags: linq, dynamics-crm, crm

```
                var advocacy = (from c in svcContext.CreateQuery("lead")
                           join a in svcContext.CreateQuery("product")
                           on c["transactioncurrencyid"] equals a["transactioncurrencyid"]
                           where a["capg_billingtimeframe"].Equals(126350000)


                           select new
                           {
                               dues = c["capg_calculatedduesbilling"],
                               product = c["capg_primaryproduct"],
                               listprice = a["price"],
                               eligibility = c.FormattedValues["capg_eligibility"]
                           });
```

That is my linq query and it is giving me the error: Invalid 'where' condition. An entity member is invoking an invalid property or method.

I have looked online everywhere and done their suggestions. I am not using Xrm.cs because late binding can be faster. I have tried using the == operand and I have tried doing (int) and Convert.ToInt32(a["capg_billingtimeframe"]) and even converting everything to a string. I will say that a["capg_billingtimeframe"] I know is an object (that's why I did those conversions.

Comment: What is Xrm.cs? Is this using Entity Framework or some other object relational mapper? Are we talking to databases or objects in memory?

Comment: Xrm.cs is a file you can generate to use early binding

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I used early bound and for getting the local I wrote:

```
OptionSetValue branch = this.InputTargetEntity.Attributes.Contains("capg_calculatorutilized") ? (OptionSetValue)this.InputTargetEntity["capg_calculatorutilized"] : (OptionSetValue)this.TargetPreImage["capg_calculatorutilized"];
```

I then had to get the Optionsets.cs using crmsvcutil and writing:

```
if (branch.Value == (int)capg_calculatorrequired.SectionA)
```

Works like a charm.

Comment: Getting the preimage is important in case the field was not populated

Answer (score 0):

I'm guessing by that integer that capg_billingtimeframe is an optionset.  If it is, you need to cast it like this:

```
where ((OptionSetValue)a["capg_billingtimeframe"]).Value == 126350000
```

Comment: The problem is that it is a global option set

Comment: As long as capg_billingtimeframe is an actual attribute on your lead entity, whether or not it references a global option set doesn't matter. If your where condition is trying to reference an optionset and you are using late-bound, you will need to do the kind of casting I show in this answer.

Comment: If you are stuck, I highly recommend using early-bound entities for your development.  For must requirements you implement, the performance difference is negligible and the development productivity boost is well worth it. I only use late-bound for code that will be running thousands of times (like in integration scenarios where huge volumes of records need to be processed, for example).